# Designing error handling in Boost Asio

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I have a Client Server application built with Boost Asio. Now I am adding Error handling to code and this is how I have planned to do.

The client will have a main thread which keeps sending command and data to the server. There will be a separate thread which keeps listening to any error messages from the server in the same socket.

The Server's main thread will read and process data from the client and when it encounters an error goes to a error handling code flow where it sends an error message to the client and goes back to read data.

Is there a better way to do error handling in this scenario?

Comment: The client can't really have to threads reading from the same socket, as there is no way to just read just a certain message from a socket, unless you send it using out-of-band (e.g. `MSG_OOB` flag to `send`). Instead let the main thread handle everything, and if an error message handle it directly instead.

Comment: Ok. I tried to handle error in the main thread itself with a read_async call after every write. But I had a strange problem of packets getting delivered very delayed from the server when it sends an error. I could not understand or debug the behavior there, that is why I was thinking of this approach(out-of-band message in the same socket).

Comment: It's not the server that sends the error messages with a delay? If messages (error or other) are passed like normal data then it will be received like normal data.

Comment: By the way, you _are_ talking about errors as actual messages being sent from the server, not things like "connection lost"?

Comment: Yes. It is not network error - error in processing the messages sent at the server.